# Tuff time, tough time, difficult time?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I would like to know what is the difference between the tuff/tough/difficult times.

I would be glad, if someone could explain me the correct usage of those.
Does it have any significant difference?

For example can I say "tuff time" if I have a "fairly bad" day?
What about the "quite bad" day?

I appreciate every answer!

Comment: The adjective ["tuff"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tuff) is slang for "cool/stylish" or non standard  spelling of "tough" and not supposed to be used in writing. Definitions of [tough](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tough#Adjective)  and [difficult](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/difficult#Adjective).

Comment: I've never really heard of "tuff" before. As for "tough time" and "difficult time", these is no significant difference in meaning.

Comment: Ohh, I see.
Nowadays I heard a lot in conversations, or in YouTube videos. Let me find you a few example:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said "tuff" is an alternate slang spelling of "tough". In my personal opinion the spelling "tuff" feels uncool and outdated. You can look at the [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tuff_ADJ&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ctuff_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btuff_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTuff_ADJ%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Ctuff_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs1%3B%3Btuff_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BTuff_ADJ%3B%2Cc0) and draw your own conclusion.

Here are some examples where tough and difficult have similar meanings:

> I'm having a tough/difficult time fitting in at my new workplace.
>
> My father just passed away and I've been having a tough/difficult time lately.

If we compare `tough/difficult` to `fairly/quite` bad. I would say that the former implies some sort of difficulties in performing a task whereas the latter just implies a generally bad situation.

> I've been trying to set up a new webpage but the web server is using a outdated OS, the electricity went out yesterday and then I forgot the admin password this morning. I'm having a pretty tough/difficult time with this.
>
> A bird pooped on my windshield, I forgot my lunch at home and my boss told me that I will have to come in to work on Saturday.  I'm having a fairly/quite/pretty bad day.